# Proving that the map is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Let $C[a,b]$ be the set of all continuous functions on $[a,b]$, with the $p$-norm for $p$ in $[1,\infty]$.  Let $T$ be the mapping defined by:

$$T:g \to g^2$$

where $g$ belongs to $C[a,b]$. Is this map continuous for all $p$?

EDIT: The $p$-norm is defined as $\|g\|_p = (\int_a^b \! |g(x)|^{p} \, \mathrm{d} x)^{1/p}$

EDIT 2: Would it be correct to show that:

$\|Tg-Tf\|_p \le K\|g-f\|_p$ for some constant $K$?

Comment: Do you know how to use TeX?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not. I will look over the TeX help and try to edit the question though.

Comment: Is that better? :)

Comment: I've just edited.

Comment: Thanks Sigur. I just made the change before you did. I did not realize posting in $TeX$ was that simple.

Comment: What do you mean as $p$-norm in this case?

Comment: Edited. The definition of p-norm in this case is the usual one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This map is not continuous for *any* $p$.

Hint: Consider a piecewise linear function with $f(a) = c$, $f(a+r)=0$, and $f=0$ on $[a+r, b]$.  Compute the $p$ norm of $f$ and $f^2$ in terms of $c,r$.  Then choose a sequence of $c_n$ and $r_n$ such that for the corresponding functions $f_n$, $\|f_n\|_p \to 0$ but $\|f_n^2\|_p \to \infty$.